# Mongoose - for each get count and select

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two schemas Advert:

```
var AdvertSchema = new Schema({
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    title: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true,
        required: 'title cannot be empty'
    },
    advert: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        required: 'advert cannot be empty'
    },
    sport: [{
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Sport'
    }],
});
mongoose.model('Advert', AdvertSchema);
```

and Sport:

```
var SportSchema = new Schema({
    sportName: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        required: 'sport cannot be empty'
    }
});
mongoose.model('Sport', SportSchema);
```

And I would like to know how can I for each sport get count of adverts and select `_id` and `sportName` of Sport schema. Note that in Advert schema is sport as array. The result then should be something like this:

```
[{
    _idOfSport: "some ID",
    sportName: "sport name",
    countOfSportAdverts: "number"
},
etc for other sports...
]
```

I guess I can use aggregation framework but I don't know how. Is it somehow possible to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this could do the trick:

```
Sport.find({}, function(err, sports) {
    var results = [], sportMap = {};

    sports.forEach(function(sport) {
        sportMap["_idOfSport"] = sport._id;
        sportMap["sportName"] = sport.sportName;
        Advert.aggregate([
            {
                $match: {
                    sport: sport._id
                }
            },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: null,
                    count: { $sum: 1 }
                }
            }
        ], function(err, res){
               sportMap["countOfSportAdverts"] = res[0].count;
               results.push(sportMap);              
        });
    });     
});
```